# Would be vs would have been in an ACT question

Tags: word-choice

A recent ACT test has the following passage:

> In December 2009, the
>   research arm of the U.S. Department of Defense, known as DARPA,
>   sponsored a high-tech scavenger hunt.  For this challenge, ten
>   eight-foot-wide red weather balloons were delivered to nine states
>   across the country, tethered to the ground in a public place, and sent
>   one hundred feet into the air.  The winner ***would be*** the team to
>   identify the latitude and longitude of all ten balloons first.

Possible answers for the bold words:

> **F.** No Change
>   **G.** would have been
>   **H.** has been
>   **J.** will be

Since the passage refers to 2009, I answered "would have been"; however, the answer booklet received after the test indicates the correct answer is "No change".  I am struggling to see why this is so.

Thank you

Comment: 'Would be' here is used to indicate 'future from point in the past referred to' (ie future reckoned from December 2009).

Comment: Thank you.  What is the best way to know this?  The word "sent" in the previous sentence is in the past tense.  By my determination every word in this passage is in the past tense including another sentence that I did not include. "By the end of the contest, many teams had competed for the prize."  If I have a similar question I think I would make the same mistake since I do not have a "rule" or an "indicator" to follow.

Comment: You could ***also*** have used the past tense: *the winner was*. But that wasn't one of the choices.